# Box.com How to Logout OAuth User so they can login with a different account?

Tags: ios, swift, box-api

I am able to login the user with OAuth and the first time they can enter their email/password on the redirected Box.com auth webpage. But once user is authenticated and later I want to log them out of the current box.com account, I have tried the following:

```
 1. client?.session.revokeTokens()  { result in ...
        
 2. KeychainTokenStore().clear() { result in ...
        
 3. client?.destroy() { result in ...
```

All of the above methods return success but afterwards when I try to login the user agian with:

```
sdk?.getOAuth2Client(tokenStore: KeychainTokenStore(), context:self) { [weak self] result in ...
```

the box.com login screen just offers "Grant Access To Box" and "Deny Access to Box" buttons with previous account email displayed. There is no option to change the user or enter new email/password. What am I missing?